# AWS invoke cross account lambda via Cloudwatch Event Bus

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-event-bridge

I have a AWS lambda function deployed in multiple accounts. I'm looking for a way to schedule to trigger these lambda function from master account via Cloudwatch Event Bus. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In line with what @amitd is suggesting you need to implement something like this (Using EventBridge , EventBus).

[image]

To configure cross-account event bridge communication following needs to be done. I am providing sample events and filters, you can replace the event and filters as per requirement.

**Steps to be performed on Account B: Receiver account**

1. Create an event bus named event-bus-b. Put the resource-based policy as shown below.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [{
    "Sid": "WebStoreCrossAccountPublish",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
      "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<account-A>:root"
    },
    "Action": "events:PutEvents",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:events:<your-region>:<Account-B>:event-bus/event-bus-b"
  }]
}
```

2. Create a rule in account B let's calls it eb-rule-b. In this Rule select event-bus-b as a source event bus.
3. Provision following event filter pattern:

Event pattern:

```
{
  "detail-type": [
    "uoe"
  ],
  "source": [
    "somesource"
  ]
}
```

Also, test the pattern using the test event.

Test Event:

```
  {
  "version": "0",
  "id": "55fghj-89a9-a0b3-1ccb-79c25c7d6cd2",
  "detail-type": "uoe",
  "source": "somesource",
  "account": "<ACCOUNT_ID>",
  "time": "2020-04-24T13:53:21Z",
  "region": "<YOUR_REGION>",
  "resources": [],
  "detail": {
   "userOrg" : "OrgName" 
  }
}
```

3. Select the event bus event-bus-b in the drop-down.
4. Select the target "Lambda"
5. Put the ARN of the event bus which you have created in Account B.

```
arn:aws:lambda:<your-region>:<AccountB>:function:<AccountBLambda>
```

6. Also check on the check box "Create a new role for this specific resource". This will create a role in account A which enables lambda execution.
7. Click on create and create the rule.
8. Now click on the event bus event-bus-a and click on Send events button.
9. Send a dummy event as shown below and validate that the communication between event bus and the lambda in account B is all ok.
10. If you face some issue in this plumbing refer to :https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-troubleshooting.html#eb-lam-function-not-invoked
11. Once we are good in Account B ( i.e we are able to invoke the lambda by sending events on the event bus, configure other accounts by following the same steps.

**Steps to be performed on Account A: Sender account**

1. Create an event bus event-bus-a in account A.
2. Create a rule eb-rule-a in account A with the following details:

Event pattern:

```
{
  "detail-type": [
    "uoe"
  ],
  "source": [
    "somesource"
  ]
}
```

Also, test the pattern using the test event.

Test Event:

```
  {
  "version": "0",
  "id": "55fghj-89a9-a0b3-1ccb-79c25c7d6cd2",
  "detail-type": "uoe",
  "source": "somesource",
  "account": "<ACCOUNT_ID>",
  "time": "2020-04-24T13:53:21Z",
  "region": "<YOUR_REGION>",
  "resources": [],
  "detail": {
   "userOrg" : "OrgName" 
  }
}
```

3. Select the event bus event-bus-a in the drop-down.
4. Select the target "Event bus in different account or Region"
5. Put the ARN of the event bus which you have created in Account B.

```
arn:aws:events:<your-region>:<Account-B>:event-bus/event-bus-b
```

6. Also check on the check box "Create a new role for this specific resource". This will create a role in account A which enables the users in account A to publish on account b event bus. The below policy is auto-created and you don't need to do anything.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "events:PutEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                arn:aws:events:<your-region>:<Account-B>:event-bus/event-bus-b
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

7. Click on create and create the rule.
8. Now click on the event bus event-bus-a and click on Send events button.
9. Provide details and click on send.

[image]

Sample event:

```
  {
  "version": "0",
  "id": "55fghj-89a9-a0b3-1ccb-79c25c7d6cd2",
  "detail-type": "uoe",
  "source": "somesource",
  "account": "<ACCOUNT_ID>",
  "time": "2020-04-24T13:53:21Z",
  "region": "<YOUR_REGION>",
  "resources": [],
  "detail": {
   "userOrg" : "OrgName" 
  }
}
```

10. Event will propagate to the event bus defined in account B.
11. Repete from steps 4- 10 for all other accounts ( i.e create multiple targets in the same rule).
12. Once configured a single event in Account A will propagates to multiple accounts and you will achieve the necessary fanning.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer following options and related documentation from AWS;

1. Using CloudWatchEvents:

a.  [Sending and Receiving Events Between AWS Accounts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/CloudWatchEvents-CrossAccountEventDelivery.html)

b.  [Cross-Account Delivery of CloudWatch Events](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-cross-account-delivery-of-cloudwatch-events/)

OR

2. Using Amazon EventBridge:

a.  [Simplifying cross-account access with Amazon EventBridge](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/simplifying-cross-account-access-with-amazon-eventbridge-resource-policies/)

b.  [Sending and recieving Amazon EventBridge events between AWS accounts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-cross-account.html)

Comment: In the **master account** is it possible to schedule and put event something like this where user defined key/value passed to indicate which lambda function to be triggered `{
  "version": "0",
  "id": "89d1a02d-5ec7-412e-82f5-13505f849b41",
  "detail-type": "Scheduled Event",
  "source": "aws.events",
  "account": "123456789012",
  "time": "2016-12-30T18:44:49Z",
  "region": "us-east-1",
  "resources": [
    "arn:aws:events:us-east-1:123456789012:rule/SampleRule"
  ],
 ** "detail": {
 "lamdaToInvoke": "Pass the labmda function name/arn to be invoked"
  }**
}`